# jQuery dialog: how to prevent closing the dialog + an extra get request!

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

The work flow:
user click the button, a dialog box opens with a search form. An ajax post request is sent to the server, and get a json response. I get the callback on success handler. Now two issues.

1. the dialog closes upon success callback (successFn). I get the json response in the success call back, and I want the user to see the result and press close button to terminate the dialog,.

   1. Soon after the dialog closes, a get request is sent to server. After closing the dialog by itself, the url is like http://localhost:8080/search?query= . I do not send any GET request explicitly

   jQuery(document).ready( function(){       
               jQuery("#myButton").click( showDialog );

   ```
           $myWindow = jQuery('#myDiv');

           $myWindow.dialog({ width: 400, autoOpen:false, title:'Hello World',
                   overlay: { opacity: 0.5, background: 'black'},  
                   modal: true,    
                   /*open: function (type, data) {
                       // include modal into form
                       $(this).parent().appendTo($("form:first"));
                   },      */          
                   buttons: {
                       "Submit Form": function() { $('form#myform').submit();},
                       "Cancel": function() {$(this).dialog("close");}
                           }
                   });
           });            


   var showDialog = function() {
       $myWindow.show(); 
       $myWindow.dialog("open");    
       }

   var closeDialog = function() {
       $myWindow.dialog("close");
   }

   var successFn = function (response) {   
           var obj = JSON.parse(response); 
           $("#result").html('').html(obj.name);
   }
   var errorFn =  function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
               $("#myform").parent().html('').html(xhr.statusText);
               }
   var query = $("input#query").val(); 
   var dataString = 'query='+ query ;  

   $('form#myform').submit(function(){
       $.ajax({
           type: 'post',
           dataType: 'json',
           url: '/search',
           async: false,
           data: $("#myform").serialize(),
           success: successFn,
           error: errorFn
       });
   });
   ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be a good idea to add `method="post"` to your form to avoid any accidental GET data being sent.

Adding return false; to the success function may stop the dialog from closing. I'll test this if I can.

Edit: also check that all your code is inside `jQuery(document).ready( function(){`

Hope that helps!

Comment: thank you for the help... both your suggestions were quite helpful, but still I couldn't get it to work.. I had some part outside document ready.. also, I added method="post" to the form.. then I could see that it sends two post messages back to back.. I think it is the way I submit ajax form.. bot sure how to solve it though, still searching.. thanks

Comment: I tried to block close through beforeClose event.. but the dialog closes .. i think it has to do with the double post message as the second one navigate away from the form..

Comment: I marked urs as best answer as it led me to the sol.. I had to add return false;  after the ajax call, inside   $('form#myform').submit(function(){ ...} .. thanks again

Answer (score 1):

I think you just need to add `return false`.

```
"Submit Form": function() { $('form#myform').submit(); return false;},
```